# Grid Checkbox value not changed, how to get value on button click?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, checkbox

i am using asp.net for my web application when i click on checkbox inside gridview and after that i check its value on button click it does not show me the exact value
here is asp code

```
<asp:GridView ID="dgvMenu" runat="server" Width="100%" CssClass="grid" GridLines="None"
                                                AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                                                <Columns>

                                                    <asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <HeaderTemplate>
                                                            View
                                                        </HeaderTemplate>
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="View" runat="server" Checked="<%#Bind('View') %>" />
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                        <ItemStyle Width="50px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                                    </asp:TemplateField>


                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Menu" HeaderText="Menu Name">
                                                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" CssClass="firstcol" />
                                                        <ItemStyle CssClass="firstcol" />
                                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                                </Columns>
                                            </asp:GridView>
```

and here is its vb version to get its value on button click version

```
For Each item As GridViewRow In dgvMenu.Rows
            Dim MenuName As String = item.Cells.Item(1).Text
            Dim chkView As CheckBox = DirectCast(item.FindControl("View"), CheckBox)
        Next
```

i want to check its value whether its checked or unchecked so that i can process its value

Comment: Where is your Button, below the GridView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your binding your GridView even on postbacks. You should only bind it `if not PageIsPostback`.

Put this into Page_Load:

```
Private Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        ' following function loads data and binds it to the GridView '
        BindGrid()
    End If
End Sub
```

If you DataBind the Grid on every postback, ViewState cannot be reloaded, hence all changed values are lost and events will not be triggered correctly.

Comment: thanks budy i was mess up with all the debugging and controlls because i'm new in web development